# How can I create the .Xauthority file on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, x11, rdp, x11-forwarding

I create an EC2 instance with Amazon Linux 2 (MATE DE) and run a script ([*via the user data option*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)) that perfroms a number of operations (including executing `xhost +` ([*why?*](https://superuser.com/q/153859))). What I'm looking to then do, is connect to that instance via ssh and run a GUI program on it (*note*: I'm looking to just give the command via ssh and for the actual program GUI to appear on the instance itself, not ssh).

So I do the following:

```
ssh -i "key.pem" ec2-user@address
export DISPLAY=:10 
obs-studio
```

And in response to that last command I get:

`Can't find source path /tmp/.X11-unix/X10: No such file or directory`

That is because in order to do what I'm trying to do I need both the **DISPLAY environment variable** to be set and for the **.Xauthority** file to exist. But as is, the .Xauthority file does not exist which is evident when running `ls -a` on */home/ec2-user* where we get:

`.  ..  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  .cache  .config  .icons  .local  recAutomation  .ssh  .var`

What I found is that when I connect to my instance via RDP, the .Xauthority file gets created and then I can run `obs-studio` from my ssh connection without issue.

So if I do (from my ssh connection):

```
sudo passwd ec2-user [*and set a password*]

sudo openssl req -x509 -sha384 -newkey rsa:3072 -nodes -keyout /etc/xrdp/key.pem -out /etc/xrdp/cert.pem -days 365 [*and set the different options*]
```

And then open up Remote Desktop Connection and connect to my instance as ec2-user with the password I set, now voila the .Xauthority file gets created. So back to my ssh session if I run `ls -a` once more we get:

`.  ..  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  .cache  .config  .dbus  Desktop  .ICEauthority  .icons  .local  .pcsc10  recAutomation  .ssh  thinclient_drives  .var  .vnc  .Xauthority  .xsession-errors`

Trying to now run `obs-studio` from my ssh session works as expected (the GUI opens up on the isntance itself) because the .Xauthority file now exists, and it works regardless of if I close down my RDP session or not.

What I'm looking to do is somehow create that .Xauthority file without manually connecting to my instance via RDP.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly how you're running ssh to connect to this server, along with any relevant entries from your _.ssh/config_ file. What are you hoping to accomplish with `export DISPLAY=:10.0`? What display are you expecting the application to appear on? Are you expecting to tunnel the application through ssh to your desktop system?

Comment: @Kenster Thanks for replying. I just edited my question and it should now be a bit easier to understand of the issue I'm facing.